# Gatsby Functions - How can I deploy gatsby functions that works like express-style functions to s3 and cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-ec2, gatsby, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

In Gatsby, I am using Gatsby functions which work as API. Refer it - https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/functions/

I want to deploy it on **Cloufront with S3**.
Currently, I am doing it like build the project. Copy the public folder on s3 and connect with a cloudfront. But it won't work for APIs.
It should work like an API with get, post, and put methods. How can I do it? Can I do it using any Lambda@Edge or Cloudfront functions?

Can anyone help with this?